# raster not displaying below certain scale

Tags: raster, arcgis-9.3

i've clipped a raster in 20 smaller images and i can zoom in until 1:150 in the original raster but, in the smaller ones, when i go below 1:4000, the workspace goes blank.

i'm working with arcgis 9.3 and can't find any configuration/solution to this problem.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the pyramids on the images?  When you clipped the images, did you reduce the resolution by accident?

Comment: all the images, including the original one, are have the same resolution. regarding the pyramids, i even tried to rebuild them in version 10, but the result is the same: the vectorial layers remain visible, the rasters don't.

Answer (score 1):

I remember having a similar problem owing to incorrect coordinate system definition.  Can you a) verify that your rasters have a coordinate system defined and b) it is the correct coordinate system?

Comment: they all have coordinate system defined and it's the correct one. If I open a road shape of those areas, the roads line up perfectly with the rasters. the project opened in arcgis 10 is fine, but I have to work in 9.3

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this would have happened from clipping the data but, do you have a visible scale range set on the layers?  Go to the layer properties, in the general tab, and check the scale range.

Comment: nope, "don't show layer when zoomed" is unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried recalculating the spatial index?

Comment: nope, removing the spatial index and adding a new one didn't resolve it.